# How does dragging a body affect your AP?

Tags: invisible-inc

Dragging a body "slows" your movement speed down, which basically means that your agent has less available AP while dragging a body.

How much is your AP reduced while dragging a body, and how does adding levels in the Strength stat reduce the AP loss? Is there some kind of formula for it?

Answer (score 2):

By default it costs 3 times as much as normal movement. The strength upgrades, and the augment can all substract 0.5 from that, meaning that if you have all 3, it costs 1.5 times as much as normal movement.

The game tracks fractional AP, and displays it rounded down. Normal movement costs 1 AP for adjacent, 1.41 AP (square root 2) for diagonal square.

Source: I looked in the source code, and it was also discussed on the forums.

Answer (score -1):

What I've got so far:

8 APs --> 2 APs without Strength (default agent)
12 APs --> 4 APs with Strength 2 (drag +1)
Roughly half with Strength 4? (drag +2)

So at a glance, it seems that there is a cost multiplier that goes down (4x, 3x, 2x). I haven't tried the Augment that increases drag speed further. Will have to try if the lack of information prevails.

Comment: You should find out first, then answer